# Jquery custom validator

Tags: jquery-validate

I'm using a jquery validate.  This is my form:

```
<form >
<input type="text" id="n1" />
<input type="text" id="n2" />
<input type="text" id="n3" />
</form>
```

This are my rules:

```
$('form').validate({
      rules:{n1:'number', n2:'number', n3:{number:true, required:true }}
});
```

But I need to show  only one message for 3 inputs. show only one error label when 1, 2 or 3 inputs are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need something like this

```
var msg = { number: 'your msg here'};
$('form').validate({
    rules:{n1:'number', n2:'number', n3:{number:true, required:true }}
    messages: { n1: msg, n2: msg, n3: msg }
});
```

Comment: thanks, but That script will make 3 msgs with same text, but I need only one msg.

Comment: Sorry, didnt have time to test it. If you didnt solve it yet, I will take a look when I get home.